# Get body of HTTP response in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to get the body of a HTTP response with Clojure, with a handler. However the `http-agent` function hangs without returning.

This will print the response, and then hang without returning:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.http.agent])

(def text (result (http-agent "http://jsonip.com"
                   :method "GET")))
(println text)
```

This will print `"Handling..."`, then hang indefinitely:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.http.agent])

(defn do-stuff
  "handler"
  [response]
  (do 
    (println "Handling...")
    (slurp (string response))))

(def text (result (http-agent "http://jsonip.com"
  :method "GET"
  :handler do-stuff)))

(println (str "text! " text))
```

How can I get the http-agent method to stop hanging? In the second case I've listed above, how can I get the handler to return the response body?

Thanks for your help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second piece of code you have not printed out what is slurped. Should be like this -

```
(println (slurp (string response)))
```